# Specifications of SQL CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

i hope this is not a repeated question

does anyone have an idea about the specs of CE SQL for example max size, max concurrent users.
how is it different from SQL express

Comment: "it did not work for me" is not an answerable question. Please ask a specific question or this will be closed.

Comment: @Dour High Arch: i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document compares the 2 products: http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/7/A47B7B0E-976D-4F49-B15D-F02ADE638EBE/Compact_Express_Comparison.doc

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft SQL Server [site](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) has extensive documentation on all versions of SQL server, including specs and comparisons.

The most significant difference between SQL Server Express and Compact editions is that CE runs in-process. That is, it is part of your application, web page, service, or whatever. Your application has total control of the data and nothing else typically has access unless it goes through your code. CE can be installed and run under a User account, and databases are standalone files that can be copied, emailed, deleted, or whatever from Windows Explorer.

SQL Express is a service typically installed by an administrator. It is a separate process that your application makes requests to; your application does not control it or the data.

There are other differences, but this is the major one. Yes, you can do things to allow multiple access to SQL CE files or install Express with your app and run it when your app launches, but this problematic and not advised.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

> SQL Server Compact Edition 4
>
> Today we are also shipping SQL Server Compact Edition 4 (aka SQL CE 4).  SQL CE is a free, >embedded, database engine that enables easy database storage.
>
> No Database Installation Required
>
> SQL CE does not require you to run a setup or install a database server in order to use >it.  You can simply copy the SQL CE binaries into the \bin directory of your ASP.NET >application, and then your web application can use it as a database engine.  No setup or >extra security permissions are required for it to run. You do not need to have an >administrator account on the machine. Just copy your web application onto any server and >it will work. This is true even of medium-trust applications running in a web hosting >environment.
>
> SQL CE runs in-memory within your ASP.NET application and will start-up when you first >access a SQL CE database, and will automatically shutdown when your application is >unloaded.  SQL CE databases are stored as files that live within the \App_Data folder of >your ASP.NET Applications.
>
> Works with Existing Data APIs
>
> SQL CE 4 works with existing .NET-based data APIs, and supports a SQL Server compatible >query syntax.  This means you can use existing data APIs like ADO.NET, as well as use >higher-level ORMs like Entity Framework and NHibernate with SQL CE.  This enables you to >use the same data programming skills and data APIs you know today.
>
> Supports Development, Testing and Production Scenarios
>
> SQL CE can be used for development scenarios, testing scenarios, and light production >usage scenarios.  With the SQL CE 4 release we’ve done the engineering work to ensure that >SQL CE won’t crash or deadlock when used in a multi-threaded server scenario (like >ASP.NET).  This is a big change from previous releases of SQL CE – which were designed for >client-only scenarios and which explicitly blocked running in web-server environments.  >Starting with SQL CE 4 you can use it in a web-server as well.
>
> There are no license restrictions with SQL CE.  It is also totally free.
>
> Tooling Support with VS 2010 SP1
>
> Visual Studio 2010 SP1 adds support for SQL CE 4 and ASP.NET Projects.  Read my VS 2010 >SP1 and SQL CE 4 blog post to learn more about what it enables.